# This code does work in phpMyAdmin, but doesn't in PHP syntax

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: The Database]

So I wanted to get all values in one column from a specific table.
I did this:

```
$syntax = 'SELECT Ubah FROM dua WHERE Ubah IS NOT NULL';
$naik = mysqli_query($this->con, $syntax);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($naik);
echo count($row).'<br>';
```

But the echo doesn't work, it displays 2. And when I did a var_dump, it also just displayed two array values.

The strange thing is that the code `SELECT Ubah FROM dua WHERE Ubah IS NOT NULL` works perfectly in phpMyAdmin. 
So what am I missing now?

**EDIT:**
So basically I want to echo some specific array value (5 highest values):

```
function Kelompok($a=1) {
    $syntax = 'SELECT Ubah FROM dua WHERE Ubah IS NOT NULL';
    $syntax2 = 'SELECT Jenis FROM dua WHERE Jenis IS NOT NULL';
    $naik = mysqli_query($this->con, $syntax);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($naik);
    $naik2 = mysqli_query($this->con, $syntax2);
    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($naik2);
    array_multisort($row, SORT_ASC, SORT_REGULAR, $row2);
    //echo count($row2) . '<br>';
    echo $row2[$a].' sebesar '.$row[$a];
}
```

And I will call the function using this : `Kelompok (0);`, `Kelompok(1);`, ... `Kelompok(4);`.

Since it doesn't work from the beginning, I tried by using var_dump, count and stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

---

Turned out I only needed to modify the `fetch_array` thing:

```
function Kelompok($a = 1) {
    $syntax = 'SELECT Ubah FROM dua WHERE Ubah IS NOT NULL';
    $syntax2 = 'SELECT Jenis FROM dua WHERE Jenis IS NOT NULL';
    $naik = mysqli_query($this->con, $syntax);
    $row = array();
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($naik)) {
        array_push($row, $r['Ubah']);
    };
    $naik2 = mysqli_query($this->con, $syntax2);
    $row2 = array();
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($naik2)) {
        array_push($row2, $r['Jenis']);
    };
    array_multisort($row, SORT_DESC, SORT_REGULAR, $row2);
    echo $row2[$a] . ' sebesar ' . $row[$a];
}
```

Works perfectly now. Thank you, xdazz, for the input. (y)

Answer (score 4):

`mysqli_fetch_array` only return one record a time.

You have to use a loop:

```
$syntax = 'SELECT Ubah FROM dua WHERE Ubah IS NOT NULL';
$naik = mysqli_query($this->con, $syntax);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($naik)) {
  var_dump($row);
}
```

And if you only need the count, you could use `COUNT(*)`:

```
$syntax = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dua WHERE Ubah IS NOT NULL';
$naik = mysqli_query($this->con, $syntax);
$result = mysqli_fetch_array($naik);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: I don't think I can do that because eventually I want to echo $row[0], $row[1], $row[2], $row[3], $row[4]. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call the `Kelompok()` function, you perform two *new* database queries, and retrieve the first result from both queries. You need to call `mysqli_fetch_array()` in a loop to retrieve more than the first row of the results. The best solution to your problem, as I understand it, is to fetch both columns in a single query, and let the database engine do the sorting.

```php
<?php

  /* I love HEREDOC syntax. */
  $q = <<<_
  SELECT  Ubah, Jenis
    FROM  dua
   WHERE  Ubah IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY  Ubah, Jenis
_;

  $rows = array();
  $naik = mysqli_query($this->con, $q);
  if ($naik) {
    while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($naik))
      $rows[] = $r;
    mysqli_free_result ($naik); /* Always free your resources. */
  } else {
    /* Error: Query failed. */
  }

  foreach ($rows as $r) {
    echo $r['Jenis'] , ' sebestar ' , $r['Ubah'], "\n";
      /* OR */
    echo $r[1] , ' sebestar ' , $r[0], "\n";
  }
```

The [`mysqli_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) function, by default, returns the row using *both* numerical indexes `(0 => ..., 1 => ...)` and associative indexes `('Jenis' => ..., 'Ubah' => ...)`. If you only want the associative indexes, you can call [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) instead. If you're happy with numerical indexes, you can call [`mysqli_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php).